# Fundamental theorem of calculus related confusion

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I know fundamental theorem of calculus states that $$\frac d {dx} \int^x_a f(t)dt=f(x)~.$$

But does $$\frac d {dx} \int^{f(x)}_a f(t)dt=f(f(x))~?$$ Or does it equal to $$\frac d {dx} \int^{f(x)}_a f(t)dt=f(f(x))f'(x)~?$$

Comment: This is not FTC. This is Leibniz's rule.

Comment: @Allawonder  You're wrong.

Comment: @TedShifrin No. You're wrong.

Answer (score 4):

With $F(x):=\int_a^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt$, we have $F'(x)=f(x)$ and by the chain rule
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \int_a^{f(x)}f(t)\,\mathrm dt=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}F(f(x))=f'(x)F'(f(x))=f'(x)f(f(x)).$$

Answer (score 0):

Here I am going to provide you a basic idea for solving such a problem.

We all know that **[the (first) fundamental theorem of calculus is just the particular case of the *Leibniz Integral Rule*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)** where $~a(x) = a~$, a constant, $~b(x) = x~$, and $~f(x, t) = f(t)~$.

So if you know the Leibniz Integral Rule (it is also known as *Differentiation under the integral sign*), then you can tackled all such problems.

> **Leibniz Integral Rule (Differentiation under the integral sign):**
>
> Let $f(x, t)$ be a function of $x$ and $t$ such that both $f(x, t)$ and its partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ are continuous in $t$ and $x$ in some region of the $(x, t)$-plane, including $a(x) ≤ t ≤ b(x)$, and $ x_0 ≤ x ≤ x_1$. Also suppose that the functions $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are both continuous and both have continuous derivatives for $x_0 ≤ x ≤ x_1$. Then, for $x_0 ≤ x ≤ x_1$,
> $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t) dt\right)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(x,t) dt +f( x, b(x)) \frac{db}{dx}-f( x, a(x)) \frac{da}{dx}$$

${}$

Now for your problem, $~a(x)=a~$, $~b(x)=f(x)~$ and $~f(x, t) = f(t)~$. So by the above rule,
\begin{equation}\frac d {dx} \int^{f(x)}_a f(t)dt=\int_{a}^{f(x)} \frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(t) dt +f(f(x)) \left(\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\right)-f(a) \frac{da}{dx}\\=0+f(f(x))f'(x)-0~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\\=f(f(x))f'(x)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\end{equation}
and therefore $$\boxed{\frac d {dx} \int^{f(x)}_a f(t)dt=f(f(x))f'(x)}$$

Comment: The Leibnitz integral rule is a _consequence_ of the fundamental theorem of calculus. The latter is not a “particular case” of the former. The Wikipedia article that you link to says as much.

Comment: This is like making someone memorize the quotient rule in order to understand how to take the derivative of $1/x$. Or having someone learn the concept of multiplication in order to solve $3+3$.